# Textbox tag and IsHitTestVisible property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<TextBox Foreground="Black" 
         FontFamily="Times New Roman" 
         FontWeight="Bold" 
         FontSize="15" 
         MaxHeight="50" 
         Margin="6,95,40.067,0" 
         Name="txt1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         IsHitTestVisible="False" 
         Height="30" 
         Grid.Row="4" 
         Grid.Column="2"/>
```

What is the role of IsHitTestVisible property on TextBox?

Answer (score 13):

When you have a control inside another control, like, If you have a TextBox inside... lets say, another TextBox. Then by setting the `isHitTestvisible` property of the parent control to False you allow the user to type in the child TextBox. If you set it to True then the RoutedEvent will be handled at the parent control level.

This property is mostly used when you work with `Adorners`.

Answer (score 0):

> true if this element could be returned as a hit test result from at least one point; otherwise, false. The default value is true.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx)

See also: [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx)

Comment: You should use the quoteblock when copying text from elsewhere, otherwise it could mislead readers to think you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this posts

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/7c352827-b4ed-493c-8a68-58179ad801fc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx