# Click in TextBox Part of ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, textbox

We have a Style for ComboBox like:

```
<Style x:Key="OurComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <!-- omitted style Properties -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                                      Grid.Column="2"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      Focusable="false"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                                          Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                 Margin="5,3,23,1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 Focusable="False"
                                 FontFamily="Arial Narrow"
                                 FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                 Foreground="#FF404040"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 PreviewMouseDown=""
                                 Style="{x:Null}"
                                 Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                 Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                 Visibility="Hidden" />

            <!-- omitted PopUp and ControlTemplate.Triggers -->
```

And based on that, we have another more specific style

```
 <Style x:Key="comboBoxSpecialPage"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource OurComboBox}"
           TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select value" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Which leads to the text  "Select value" if nothing is selected in the ComboBox, e.g. on start of the application.

But when I click directly on the TextBox text, nothing happens.

So the question is:
How to achieve that the PopUp is opened, as it does when the rest of the
ComboBox (the part without Text) is clicked?

-edit-
If I omited interesting parts, please let me know, I will add them then.

Comment: Do you really want to implement such a behavior? Regarding the usability it is an weird solution, since you have one user action and two desired behaviors. If I use a `ComboBox` I'd expect to select the item I'm clicking on. I'd not expect the `TextBox`to switch into edit mode.

Comment: I want the ComboBox to behave as a ComboBox. I do not want the TextBox part to be editable, it shall display some text. If one clicks in the TextBox, it should popup the ComboBox. Right now, it does not. It popups if the area which is not covered by the text is clicked. How can I make it popup on click of the text?

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, now I'm getting your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps IsHitTestVisible property is what you are looking for, more info here: 
[Textbox tag and IsHitTestVisible property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564285/textbox-tag-and-ishittestvisible-property)

Comment: Sorry for answering late. Trying around with that property, but had no success up to now.

Comment: Okay, now it is working! Had to set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` and `IsEnabled="False"`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox has a property called DropDownStyle.
Set this to DropDownList and the text area is no longer editable, i.e you have to select from the list.

Comment: It is a System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox. Think is has no such property.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was thinking of the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.